# I am having trouble Creating A simple Hompage For my Flutter app "Unimplemented handling of missing static target"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The similar question of "Unimplemented handling of missing static target" and my scenario is quite different as my app is building but throwing this error.. Here's my code

main.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Pages/homepage.dart';


main() => runApp(new HomePage());
```

homepage.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tutorial1/Common%20Classes/UIApplication.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }

}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

UIApplication init = new UIApplication();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = createHomePage();
    return home;
  }

    createHomePage(){
        var homePageScaffold = createHomePageScaffold();
        return MaterialApp(home: homePageScaffold, debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
    }


    //Scaffold For Home Page
    createHomePageScaffold(){
      var homeAppbar = homeAppBar();
      var homebody = homeBody();
      var scaffold = new Scaffold(appBar: homeAppbar, body: homebody);
      return scaffold;
    }

    //AppBar For Home Page
    homeAppBar(){
      var text = init.createText('Welcome');
      var appBar = new AppBar(title: text);
      return appBar;
    }

    //Body For Home Page
    homeBody(){
      var text = init.createText("Hello");
      return new Center(child: text);
    }


}
```

UIApplication.dart Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UIApplication {
    //Create Text
    createText( String text ){
      var newText = new Text(text);
      return newText;
    }
}
```

Although my app is building and running it is throwing the error, I know it would be simpler if I use a stateless widget but why can't I use stateful widget like this ? and what does this error really mean?

Comment: Running your code locally does not result in the error that you are showing us. Also, the way you are running that Flutter app is highly inefficient. Dart is a typed language and you are declaring every variable as a `var` and making an exaggerated use of methods. Why aren't you using the standard way to write Flutter apps? Why are you even using the UIApplication class?

Comment: I am coming from a swift, kotlin background .. so I am trying learn dart separating the code blocks as much as I can so that I can understand them better.. and I found the problem .. thanks for taking your time to run my code .. cheers..

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to write Flutter properly, there are plenty of online tutorials. If you continue to write your code the way you are, you will find a lot of problems in the future and other Flutter developers will not be able to help you debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

The next time I started VSCode and ran my project the error is not showing anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Run  flutter clean and rebuild project.

This error happens when the build was built without the plugin, and is not able to synchronize files after the build, because the initial hot reload is only able to synchronize dart files, and your library depends on a native file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before, and I resolve it by just making Hot Restart.

See this link for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/76432381/15721679