# Flutter Unimplemented handling of missing static target

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing an App in Flutter, but recently I always get a `Unimplemented handling of missing static target`.

I run the App on a physical Android device because I need to communicate via Bluetooth, and that seems a bit tricky to set up in an Emulator.

I saw some Questions here where the same problem was present, but no one actually explained what happened there, and how to avoid it, and only some Trial-and-error-solutions were posted.

My error and output during running:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on K00C in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/DartVM  (17171): vm-service: Error: Unhandled exception:
E/DartVM  (17171): Unimplemented handling of missing static target
E/DartVM  (17171): #0      serviceAuthToken (dart:_vmservice:44:33)
E/DartVM  (17171): #1      serviceAuthToken (dart:_vmservice:44:14)
E/DartVM  (17171): #2      Server.serverAddress (dart:vmservice_io/server.dart:164:40)
E/DartVM  (17171): #3      Server.startup (dart:vmservice_io/server.dart:432:44)
E/DartVM  (17171): <asynchronous suspension>
E/DartVM  (17171): #4      main (dart:vmservice_io:262:12)
E/DartVM  (17171): 
E/flutter (17171): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(915)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (17171): Unimplemented handling of missing static target
E/flutter (17171): #0      serviceAuthToken (dart:_vmservice:44:33)
E/flutter (17171): #1      serviceAuthToken (dart:_vmservice:44:14)
E/flutter (17171): #2      Server.serverAddress (dart:vmservice_io/server.dart:164:40)
E/flutter (17171): #3      Server.startup (dart:vmservice_io/server.dart:432:44)
E/flutter (17171): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17171): #4      main (dart:vmservice_io:262:12)
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63455/6QCnX6crt0s=/ws
Syncing files to device K00C...
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 365: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 372: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColor
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 373: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 374: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 376: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 378: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 386: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 393: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemServiceName, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemServiceName
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 395: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemServiceName (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 398: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
I/dalvikvm(17626): Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
W/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 411: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
D/dalvikvm(17626): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
F/libc    (17626): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2bc9ce80 (code=1), thread 17726 (utter_bluetooth)
process stopped due to unexpected signal 27
Lost connection to device.
Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:63455/6QCnX6crt0s=/
```

My code:

```
// For performing some operations asynchronously
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

// For using PlatformException
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BluetoothApp(),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BluetoothAppState createState() => _BluetoothAppState();
}

class _BluetoothAppState extends State<BluetoothApp> {
  // Initializing the Bluetooth connection state to be unknown
  BluetoothState _bluetoothState = BluetoothState.UNKNOWN;
  // Initializing a global key, as it would help us in showing a SnackBar later
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  // Get the instance of the Bluetooth
  FlutterBluetoothSerial _bluetooth = FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance;
  // Track the Bluetooth connection with the remote device
  BluetoothConnection connection;

  int _deviceState;

  bool isDisconnecting = false;

  Map<String, Color> colors = {
    'onBorderColor': Colors.green,
    'offBorderColor': Colors.red,
    'neutralBorderColor': Colors.transparent,
    'onTextColor': Colors.green[700],
    'offTextColor': Colors.red[700],
    'neutralTextColor': Colors.blue,
  };

  // To track whether the device is still connected to Bluetooth
  bool get isConnected => connection != null && connection.isConnected;

  // Define some variables, which will be required later
  List<BluetoothDevice> _devicesList = [];
  BluetoothDevice _device;
  bool _connected = false;
  bool _isButtonUnavailable = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Get current state
    FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.state.then((state) {
      setState(() {
        _bluetoothState = state;
      });
    });

    _deviceState = 0; // neutral

    // If the bluetooth of the device is not enabled,
    // then request permission to turn on bluetooth
    // as the app starts up
    enableBluetooth();

    // Listen for further state changes
    FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
        .onStateChanged()
        .listen((BluetoothState state) {
      setState(() {
        _bluetoothState = state;
        if (_bluetoothState == BluetoothState.STATE_OFF) {
          _isButtonUnavailable = true;
        }
        getPairedDevices();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Avoid memory leak and disconnect
    if (isConnected) {
      isDisconnecting = true;
      connection.dispose();
      connection = null;
    }

    super.dispose();
  }

  // Request Bluetooth permission from the user
  Future<void> enableBluetooth() async {
    // Retrieving the current Bluetooth state
    _bluetoothState = await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.state;

    // If the bluetooth is off, then turn it on first
    // and then retrieve the devices that are paired.
    if (_bluetoothState == BluetoothState.STATE_OFF) {
      await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestEnable();
      await getPairedDevices();
      return true;
    } else {
      await getPairedDevices();
    }
    return false;
  }

  // For retrieving and storing the paired devices
  // in a list.
  Future<void> getPairedDevices() async {
    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];

    // To get the list of paired devices
    try {
      devices = await _bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Error");
    }

    // It is an error to call [setState] unless [mounted] is true.
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    // Store the [devices] list in the [_devicesList] for accessing
    // the list outside this class
    setState(() {
      _devicesList = devices;
    });
  }

  // Now, its time to build the UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Bluetooth"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.refresh,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: Text(
                "Refresh",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              splashColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              onPressed: () async {
                // So, that when new devices are paired
                // while the app is running, user can refresh
                // the paired devices list.
                await getPairedDevices().then((_) {
                  show('Device list refreshed');
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                visible: _isButtonUnavailable &&
                    _bluetoothState == BluetoothState.STATE_ON,
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Enable Bluetooth',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Switch(
                      value: _bluetoothState.isEnabled,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        future() async {
                          if (value) {
                            await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
                                .requestEnable();
                          } else {
                            await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
                                .requestDisable();
                          }

                          await getPairedDevices();
                          _isButtonUnavailable = false;

                          if (_connected) {
                            _disconnect();
                          }
                        }

                        future().then((_) {
                          setState(() {});
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "PAIRED DEVICES",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.blue),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'Device:',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            DropdownButton(
                              items: _getDeviceItems(),
                              onChanged: (value) =>
                                  setState(() => _device = value),
                              value: _devicesList.isNotEmpty ? _device : null,
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: _isButtonUnavailable
                                  ? null
                                  : _connected ? _disconnect : _connect,
                              child:
                                  Text(_connected ? 'Disconnect' : 'Connect'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: new BorderSide(
                              color: _deviceState == 0
                                  ? colors['neutralBorderColor']
                                  : _deviceState == 1
                                      ? colors['onBorderColor']
                                      : colors['offBorderColor'],
                              width: 3,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                          ),
                          elevation: _deviceState == 0 ? 4 : 0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "DEVICE 1",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: _deviceState == 0
                                          ? colors['neutralTextColor']
                                          : _deviceState == 1
                                              ? colors['onTextColor']
                                              : colors['offTextColor'],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: _connected
                                      ? _sendOnMessageToBluetooth
                                      : null,
                                  child: Text("ON"),
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: _connected
                                      ? _sendSerMessageToBluetooth
                                      : null,
                                  child: Text("OFF"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "NOTE: If you cannot find the device in the list, please pair the device by going to the bluetooth settings",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 2,
                          child: Text("Bluetooth Settings"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.openSettings();
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Create the List of devices to be shown in Dropdown Menu
  List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> _getDeviceItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<BluetoothDevice>> items = [];
    if (_devicesList.isEmpty) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text('NONE'),
      ));
    } else {
      _devicesList.forEach((device) {
        items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(device.name),
          value: device,
        ));
      });
    }
    return items;
  }

  // Method to connect to bluetooth
  void _connect() async {
    setState(() {
      _isButtonUnavailable = true;
    });
    if (_device == null) {
      show('No device selected');
    } else {
      if (!isConnected) {
        await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(_device.address)
            .then((_connection) {
          print('Connected to the device');
          connection = _connection;
          setState(() {
            _connected = true;
          });

          connection.input.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {
            if (isDisconnecting) {
              print('Disconnecting locally!');
            } else {
              print('Disconnected remotely!');
            }
            if (this.mounted) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          });
        }).catchError((error) {
          print('Cannot connect, exception occurred');
          print(error);
        });
        show('Device connected');

        setState(() => _isButtonUnavailable = false);
      }
    }
  }

  void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
    // Allocate buffer for parsed data
    print(data);
    int backspacesCounter = 0;
    data.forEach((byte) {
      if (byte == 8 || byte == 127) {
        backspacesCounter++;
      }
    });
    Uint8List buffer = Uint8List(data.length - backspacesCounter);
    int bufferIndex = buffer.length;

    // Apply backspace control character
    backspacesCounter = 0;
    for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (data[i] == 8 || data[i] == 127) {
        backspacesCounter++;
      } else {
        if (backspacesCounter > 0) {
          backspacesCounter--;
        } else {
          buffer[--bufferIndex] = data[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Method to disconnect bluetooth
  void _disconnect() async {
    setState(() {
      _isButtonUnavailable = true;
      _deviceState = 0;
    });

    await connection.close();
    show('Device disconnected');
    if (!connection.isConnected) {
      setState(() {
        _connected = false;
        _isButtonUnavailable = false;
      });
    }
  }

  // Method to send message,
  // for turning the Bluetooth device on
  void _sendOnMessageToBluetooth() async {
    connection.output.add(utf8.encode("1" + "\r\n"));
    await connection.output.allSent;
    show('Device Turned On');
    setState(() {
      _deviceState = 1; // device on
    });
  }

  // Method to send message,
  // for turning the Bluetooth device off
  void _sendSerMessageToBluetooth() async {
    connection.output.add(Uint8List.fromList([32, 33]));
    await connection.output.allSent;

    show('Device Turned Off');
    setState(() {
      _deviceState = -1; // device off
    });
  }

  // Method to show a Snackbar,
  // taking message as the text
  Future show(
    String message, {
    Duration duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
  }) async {
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(
          message,
        ),
        duration: duration,
      ),
    );
  }
}


void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
  // Allocate buffer for parsed data
  int backspacesCounter = 0;
  data.forEach((byte) {
    if (byte == 8 || byte == 127) {
      backspacesCounter++;
    }
  });
  Uint8List buffer = Uint8List(data.length - backspacesCounter);  //
  int bufferIndex = buffer.length;

  // Apply backspace control character
  backspacesCounter = 0;
  for (int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (data[i] == 8 || data[i] == 127) {
      backspacesCounter++;
    } else {
      if (backspacesCounter > 0) {
        backspacesCounter--;
      } else {
        buffer[--bufferIndex] = data[i];
      }
    }
  }

  // Create message if there is new line character
  String dataString = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
}
```

So if anyone knows a solution, please post it, even  if you don't know what exactly happened
Also if anyone spots other mistakes that may cause errors in the Future, please tell me!

Comment: try removing each plugin from ```pubspec.yaml``` and add them one by one to narrow down what causes this issue. Hope this could help.

Comment: Well, all the plugins are needed, so I'm not sure if that will work, but I'll give it a go

Answer (score 4):

on terminal of your IDE:
    flutter clean

and rebuild project.

This error happens when the build was built without the plugin, and is not able to synchronize files after the build, because the initial hot reload is only able to synchronize dart files, and your library depends on a native file (java / kotlin / swift / objc) then the methodchannel responds with "Not Implemented"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make Hot Restart, I had the same issue and this resolve it for me

This error happens when the build was built without a plugin, and is not able to synchronize files after the build, so hot restart will synchronize all the added files